# Diskspace on FreeBSD as a numeric value

Tags: disk-space, freebsd

I wonder if there is a way to get the capacity of a disk as a numeric value in FreeBSD.

I don't want to use `df` because it doesn't return a single numeric value, `du -sch /` takes too much time summing up.

Maybe there is a variable accessible via sysctl? I tried `sysctl -a -d | grep -e disk` but havn't found something.

Thanks in advance,

Steffen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick sketch of an `awk` physical disk usage printer (nb: only tried on Linux):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while ! [ $# -eq 0 ]; do
    df --block-size=1G | awk '$1 ~ /\/dev\/'"${1}"'/ {free+=$4; total+=$2} END {printf "%4s: %4sG / %4sG\n", "'"${1}"'", free, total}'
    shift
done
```

Save the above script as e.g. `dfsum` and run it as e.g.:

```
$ dfsum sda sdb
sda:   19G /  916G
sdb:   59G / 1834G
```

---

**EDIT:** An updated version with a header and automatic detection of disks:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
df --block-size=1G | awk '
    BEGIN {printf "%-5s%5s   %5s\n", "disk", "free", "total"}
    !match($1, "^/dev/([[:alpha:]]+)", disk) {next} \
    {free[disk[1]]+=$4; total[disk[1]]+=$2} \
    END {for (var in free) printf "%3s: %4sG / %4sG\n", var, free[var], total[var]}'
```

Note: this requires [`gawk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/).

---

**EDIT again:**

```
#!/bin/sh
df --block-size=1G |\
awk '
    BEGIN {
        printf "%-5s%5s   %5s\n", "disk", "free", "total"
    }

    !match($1, "^/dev/([[:alpha:]]+)[[:digit:]]", disk) {next} 

    {
        free[disk[1]]+=$4
        total[disk[1]]+=$2
    }

    END {
        for (var in free) {
            printf "%3s: %4sG / %4sG\n", var, free[var], total[var]
            totalfree+=free[var]
            totalsize+=total[var]
        } 
        printf "     -------------\n     %4sG / %4sG\n", totalfree, totalsize
    }
'
```

This also gives a total sum, and fixes a change in my system that occured after a restart where a column with `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`... is shown for the root filesystem in the `df` output, but also as a separate entry as `/dev/sda1`. I'm only interested in the latter.

Comment: Yes, awk would be possible. I am looking for a not-scripted solution where the value comes right out of the system (df has to store the value somewhere, right?). But, if there is none, what I suppose, I will use awk.

Comment: Well, the value from `df` is per partition. It doesn't really make sense to store a "physical free space" value, since it is dependent on file system, block size, reserved space, etc. of the separate partitions, so a "physical" value would have to take the separate partition environments into account anyway. Thus the best one could store would be a continuously updated sum of the partition values, which is what `awk` gives you. That is why I don't think there is a system-wide value stored somewhere.

Comment: True. So, I say `Hello`to awk. Thanks :)